# GCM notification not delivered immediately

Tags: php, android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I developed a simple application in android just to send notifications from one user to other.as a quick overview of my app:

1. user register in the app using phone number.
2. in my database, a new record created contain the phone number and the GCM reg ID.
3. when the user try to send a notification to another user, the application will find the reg ID of the recipient in the DB and send a notification using a php code in my server.

My problem is most of times the notification didn't delivered to the recipient.

Java Code as I said, just search for the reg ID in the DB then submit it to the PHP server, and the PHP server when communicate with the GCM server.

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","my password","database name");

// Replace with real BROWSER API key from Google APIs
$apiKey = "my api key";

// Replace with real client registration IDs 

$destinationcereg = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['destreg']);// this will provided by the app

$registrationIDs = array($destinationcereg);

// Message to be sent

$destinationcereg2 = &$destinationcereg;

// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields = array(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
    'data'              => array( "message" => 'You Recieved New Message'),
);

$headers = array( 
    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
echo ahmed;

?>
```

Also note that sometime the notification received after long time, most of times it's not received, and also sometimes it received immediately.

Can any one help me please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've this problem but I investigate it and I conclude that it's not your error. You send the message to Google and then you can't have control about the message so it's their problem (Google) like Facebook, not always you receive your notification at least I don't

Comment: Thanks lacrirra.  user3607917 could you please explain more about XMPP and how to use it and why ?